# El codigo de usuario no controló NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, asp

Tengo un proyecto que en ASP.NET el cual estoy editando con Visual Studio. Al momento de compilarlo me sale todo en orden y abre la pantalla de login pero al momento de ingresar el usuario/contraseña y seleccionar el botón de iniciar sesión me abre el visual estudio con el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene una idea que me puede estar pasando le agradezco me oriente.
A continuacion adjunto el codigo, Gracias.

```
public class Conexion
{

MySqlConnection conn;
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();

/// <summary>
/// Crea una instancia del acceso a la Base de Datos
/// </summary>

public Conexion()
{
    // Llamado al método conectar
    conectar();
}

public void conectar()
{
    try
    {
        //NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123;Database=schoolonline;Pooling=false");
        string nombrecadena = "default";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Remove(0, 1) != "")
            nombrecadena = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Remove(0, 1);

        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nombrecadena].ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Close();
            conn = null;
            conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nombrecadena].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        // Lanza la excepción en caso de no poder conectarse a la BD
        throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
    }
}

public bool probarconexion()
{
    try
    {
        conectar();
        conn.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public void desconectar()
{
    conn.Close();
}


/// <summary>
/// Devuelve un DATATABLE con los registros que resultan
/// de la ejecución de la consulta SQL pasada como parámetro
/// </summary>
/// <returns>DataTable con los registros resultado de la ejecución del comando</returns>
public DataTable traerdata()
{
    try
    {
        // Llama al método conectar para establecer a conexión
        conectar();
        // el método Open abre la conexión
        conn.Open();
        // instancia un datatable
        DataTable dtabtrae = new DataTable();
        // se crea el adaptador de datos
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptrae = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando.CommandText, conn);
        // el adaptador llena el datatable
        adaptrae.Fill(dtabtrae);
        // se cierra la conexión

        // se devuelve el datatable
        return dtabtrae;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 1042)
        {
            // Error de conexión
            throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

}

public DataSet traerset()
{
    try
    {
        // Llama al método conectar para establecer a conexión
        conectar();
        // el método Open abre la conexión
        conn.Open();
        // instancia un datatable
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // se crea el adaptador de datos
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptrae = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando.CommandText, conn);
        // el adaptador llena el datatable
        adaptrae.Fill(ds);
        // se cierra la conexión
        conn.Close();
        // se devuelve el datatable
        return ds;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 1042)
        {
            // Error de conexión
            throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Devuelve un DATAROW con el registro que resulte
/// de la ejecución de la consulta SQL pasada como parámetro
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cad">Consulta SQL a ejecutar</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public DataRow traerfila()
{
    try
    {
        conectar();
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dtabtrae = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptrae = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando.CommandText, conn);
        adaptrae.Fill(dtabtrae);


        // Se verifica la cantidad de registros del datatable
        if (dtabtrae.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // Se asigna al datarow el primer registro del datatable
            // y se devuelve
            DataRow dfiltrae = dtabtrae.Rows[0];
            return dfiltrae;
        }
        else
        {
            // En caso de que la consulta no devuelva resultados se
            // retorna null
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        throw (e);
        //if (e.Number == 1042)
        //{
        //throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
        //}
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Ejecuta una consulta de acción (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
/// sobre la BD
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cad">Consulta SQL a ejecutar</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Boolean guardadata()
{
    try
    {
        conectar();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmdguarda = new MySqlCommand(comando.CommandText, conn);
        cmdguarda.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmdguarda.Connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 1042)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}

//Ejecuta una consulta de acción (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
//sobre la BD, y en caso de AUTO INC me trae el codigo
public long guardadataid()
{
    try
    {
        long idgen;
        conectar();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmdguarda = new MySqlCommand(comando.CommandText, conn);
        cmdguarda.ExecuteNonQuery();
        idgen = cmdguarda.LastInsertedId;
        conn.Close();
        cmdguarda.Connection.Close();
        return idgen;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 1042)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error conectando a base de datos, consulte con su administrador de red", e);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Crea un comando en base a una sentencia SQL.
/// Ejemplo:
/// <code>SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE campo1=@campo1, campo2=@campo2</code>
/// Guarda el comando para el seteo de parámetros y la posterior ejecución.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sentenciaSQL">La sentencia SQL con el formato: SENTENCIA [param = @param,]</param>

public void CrearComando(string sentenciaSQL)
{
    this.comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    this.comando.CommandText = sentenciaSQL;
}

/// <summary>
/// Setea un parámetro como nulo del comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro cuyo valor será nulo.</param>
public void AsignarParametroNulo(string nombre)
{
    AsignarParametro(nombre, "", "NULL");
}

/// <summary>
/// Asigna un parámetro de tipo cadena al comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="valor">El valor del parámetro.</param>
public void AsignarParametroCadena(string nombre, string valor)
{
    AsignarParametro(nombre, "'", valor);
}

/// <summary>
/// Asigna un parámetro de tipo entero al comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="valor">El valor del parámetro.</param>
public void AsignarParametroEntero(string nombre, int valor)
{
    AsignarParametro(nombre, "", valor.ToString());
}


/// <summary>
/// Asigna un parámetro de tipo doble al comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="valor">El valor del parámetro.</param>
public void AsignarParametroDouble(string nombre, double valor)
{
    AsignarParametro(nombre, "", valor.ToString());
}

/// <summary>
/// Asigna un parámetro al comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="separador">El separador que será agregado al valor del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="valor">El valor del parámetro.</param>
private void AsignarParametro(string nombre, string separador, string valor)
{
    int indice = this.comando.CommandText.IndexOf(nombre);
    string prefijo = this.comando.CommandText.Substring(0, indice);
    string sufijo = this.comando.CommandText.Substring(indice + nombre.Length);
    this.comando.CommandText = prefijo + separador + valor + separador + sufijo;
}

/// <summary>
/// Asigna un parámetro de tipo fecha al comando creado.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nombre">El nombre del parámetro.</param>
/// <param name="valor">El valor del parámetro.</param>
public void AsignarParametroFecha(string nombre, DateTime valor)
{
    AsignarParametro(nombre, "'", valor.ToString());
}


}
```

Comment: No debes tener el connection string configurado en el web.config

Comment: y por favor, los errores tienen que estar en la pregunta, no en una imagen.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que no tengas la variable "default" definida en el web.config. Si la tienes definida entonces como dice hardkoded es problema de configuración.

Comment: Muchas gracias hardkoded y PabloOliver, efectivamente tuve que modificar el web.config y se soluciono. Gracias nuevamente